# How do I show a message before system.exit in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to cover possible options when using the JOptionPane.showInputDialog box.The user must enter a "Y" to continue running the code, "N" will cancel the procedure and clicking the cancel button should do the same as typing "N". But, when the user clicks cancel, I want to show the a message like "You have chosen to cancel the order" before the System.exit(0) runs. I have not been able to get that message to display. Below is the code I have so far:

```
inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an order (Y/N)"); 
        if(inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Since you are not entering an order....\n" +
            "The program will close.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(inputStr.equals(null)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to cancel this order");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(!inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid character.\n" +
            "Enter a 'Y' or 'N' only.");
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: This code is working as expected.

Comment: Why don't you create an option pane with three choices, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION. Then you will have values for each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION:

```
Object[] options = {"Yes","No","Cancel"};
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
        "Continue?",
        "Would you like to continue?",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        options,
        options[2]);
if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicked Yes");
} else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicked No");
} else if (n == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Clicked Cancel");
} else {
    System.out.println("something else (like clicked the 'x' button)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing inputStr.equals(null) to inputStr == null

Works fine as long as you change the if statments around to what they are below.

```
String inputStr;
    inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an order (Y/N)"); 
    if(inputStr == null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to cancel this order");
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Since you are not entering an order....\n" +
        "The program will close.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(!inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have entered an invalid character.\n" +
        "Enter a 'Y' or 'N' only.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a delay in between `exit(0)` and message with [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

And Change

```
if(inputStr.equals(null)){
```

with

```
if(inputStr == null){
```

`==` will always compare for identity - i.e. whether the two values are references to the same object. This is also called reference equality. Java doesn't have any user-defined operator overloading.

`.equals()` will call the virtual equals method declared by Object, unless a more specific overload has been introduced by the compile-time type of `inputStr`.

Of course, if `inputStr` is null then you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `inputStr.equals(null)`.

Comment: Why? JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() blocks the execution.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() blocks the execution thats right but the question asked says he doesnot have to do that so i mention an opinion about swing.Timer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Think about

```
if(inputStr.equals(null)){
```

Does it make sense to call the 'equals()' method on a 'null' object? Because if inputStr is null, then you would not be able to call a method on it.

The correct syntax would be:

```
if(inputStr == null){
```

and do this as the first 'if', to protect you from a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

This what i will do

```
 String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an order (Y/N)");

            if (inputStr == null || inputStr.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Cancelled");
            } else {

                if (inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Since you are not entering an order....\n"
                                    + "The program will close.");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (!inputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "You have entered an invalid character.\n"
                                    + "Enter a 'Y' or 'N' only.");

                }
            }
```

Goodluck